# Upgrading from Microsoft Enterprise Library 2.0 to 5.1

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

I am working on an older project that is using various blocks from Microsoft Enterprise Library version 2.0. I'd like to upgrade to 5.1.

The blocks we are using are Data access, Exception handling and Logging.

Would their be any issues if I just referenced the new libraries? Or would this potentially break old code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using factory facades to get EntLib objects, most of them are still there. Your config would likely need to be updated to reflect the new schema.

Also, take a look at the [Migration Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20476). It doesn't cover Entlib2.0 -> 5.0 migration but includes 3.1->5.0 migration, which should be sufficient, since there were no breaking changes in the API between v3.x and v2.0.